# How to programmatically mark disclosures as disclosures for SEO/accessibility purposes?

Tags: html, seo, accessibility, semantic-markup

I have a lot of disclosures at the bottom of the footer of my site. The disclosures are in paragraph tags within a div with an id of "disclosures". Like this:

```html
<div id="disclosures">
  <p>Here's a disclosure</p>
  <p>Here's another disclosure</p>
</div>
```

Is there a way to programmatically mark this div and/or these paragraphs as a "disclosure" so that search engine bots and screen readers will understand that these are disclosures and not just regular page content?  The disclosures contain a lot of keywords that we don't want the page to rank for - we want other pages to rank for those keywords. So, we're trying to think of a way to keep the bots from reading that text or understanding it's not high level copy.

Comment: How is a disclosure not page content? Anyway, it doesn't matter. This won't affect anything.

Comment: Well the disclosures contain a lot of keywords that we don't want the page to rank for - we want other pages to rank for those keywords. So, we're trying to think of a way to keep the bots from reading that text or understanding it's not high level copy.

Comment: Doesn't matter. That text won't prevent you from ranking for the other content. And unless your site becomes *huge* you won't rank for disclosure text (that people aren't looking for anyway).

Comment: In which way would this affect the accessibility?

Comment: Screen readers could say, "Disclosures", then list them off. I'm more concerned about SEO than accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

Semantically,the correct element to use for this is the HTML5 `<footer>` element. This will allow assistive technology to know this is a landmark region and is the footer text (contentinfo role).

As far as SEO, I am not sure whether the search engines process this markup but it is your best bet for the future if they do not do so today.